# if-elif loop won't run

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new and attempting to make a simple if-elif loop. It works in other parts of the code but this loop acts like there is no user input. It doesn't even throw an error code, it just runs the first if-body and then skips the elif.

I have tried using just if-else but that has the same effect.
I have also tried including the code rather than calling the function, no difference.
This is my first posted question so please feel free to make suggestions on how I should post to help other people understand me better.

```
#run loop for reroll

reroll = input("Reroll? Y  or N:")

if reroll == "N" or "n":
    Do_Not_Reroll()
elif reroll == "Y" or "y":
    Reroll_user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
reroll = input("Reroll? Y  or N:")

if reroll == "N" or reroll == "n":
    # do some thing
elif reroll == "Y" or reroll == "y":
    #do some thing
```

you can also do like this:

```
if reroll in("N","n"):
    #do some thing
elif reroll in("Y","y"):
    #do some thing
```

Comment: That worked and I would never have thought of that. Why does it need REROLL restated?

Comment: because if you write if reroll == "N" or "n" then "n" becomes a separate statement and "n" is always true. so elif won't execute

Answer (score 3):

When you say `if reroll == "N" or "n":`, you're actually executing the statement
`(if reroll == "N") or ("n")`. Because strings are truthy in Python, the second part of that equation is always considered to be true. Thus, the first half of the expression is ignored.

To correct this, you need to specify the variable again:

```
if reroll == "Y" or reroll == "y":
```

In addition to this, ensure that `Reroll_user` is `Reroll_user()` (assuming it is a function).

Answer (score 1):

Slight tweaks to your current code to do what you're attempting to do:

Alernative 1:

```
reroll = input("Reroll? Y  or N:")

if reroll in ("N","n"):
    Do_Not_Reroll()
elif reroll in ("Y","y"):
    Reroll_user
```

Alternative 2:

```
reroll = input("Reroll? Y  or N:")

if reroll == "N" or reroll == "n":
    Do_Not_Reroll()
elif reroll == "Y" or reroll == "y":
    Reroll_user
```

Alternative 3:

```
reroll = input("Reroll? Y  or N:")

if reroll.lower() == "n":
    Do_Not_Reroll()
elif reroll.lower() == "y":
    Reroll_user
```

Comment: Alternative 4: reroll=input("Reroll? Y or N:").lower(), then you can compare reroll=="n", etc..